# padding or margin wrong or both

Tags: html, margin

I tried something with divs in html, and normally it isn't a problem. However I encountered a problem and I don't find my mistake.

The menu div is supposed to be in the center of the header div and there should be no margin at the top.

here is the example with the error: http://jsfiddle.net/j83eb/

here is the html:

```
<div id="header">
        <div id="menu"> 
            <ul>
                <li><a class="nav-element" href="#">News</a></li>
                <li><a class="nav-element" href="#">Turnier</a></li>
                <li><a class="nav-element" href="#">Ergebnisse</a></li>
                <li><a class="nav-element" href="#">Impressionen</a></li>
                <li><a class="nav-element" href="#">Anmeldung</a></li>
                <li><a class="nav-element" href="#">Impressum</a></li>
            </ul> 
        </div>
    </div>
```

and the css:

```
#header {
    padding: 0;
    margin:0;
    background: #003399;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
#menu a {
    display: block;
    width: 150px;
    height: 50px;
    }
#menu {
    padding:0;
margin-right:auto;
margin-left:auto;
line-height:50px;
width: 950px;
height: 50px;
    }
#menu ul li {
    display: block;
    width: 150px;
    height: 50px;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: normal;
    list-style: none;
    margin:0;
    paddin:0;
    line-height:50px;
}
.nav-element:link {
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.nav-element:visited {
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #81b4e3;
}
.nav-element:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #1a589d;
}
.nav-element:active {
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #C00;
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below will fix it (remove margin/padding from `ul`)

```
#menu ul {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

And the [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/doitlikejustin/j83eb/1/)

Answer (score 0):

As said above, you'll want to clear the default margins on the `<ul>` element. (No need to clear the padding, there is none). I also removed the height and line-height from everything since that isn't necessary and will likely just cause problems in the future.

Also, make sure to look through your CSS before sending it out for help. There were a number of properties with typos as well as duplicate properties.

http://jsfiddle.net/j83eb/3/